# RestKit: mapping JSON array of strings

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

Given the following JSON:

```
{
   "someKey":"someValue",
   "otherKey":"otherValue",
   "features":[
      "feature1",
      "feature2",
      "feature3"
   ]
}
```

I am mapping this JSON into `NSManagedObject`s with `RKMapperOperation` and `RKEntityMapping`(in this example I would have 2 entity mappings: one for the top level object and another one for my Feature class).

The top level object mapping is trivial: two attribute mappings plus a relationship one(features) for the relation with Feature.

My question is,how to map the features JSON array into an array of Feature objects? The Feature class has just one property `name` where I want to store "feature1", "feature2", etc plus a reference to the parent object (the top level one). Something like this:

```
@interface Feature : NSManagedObject

//In the implementation file both properties are declared with @dynamic.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyTopLevelObject *myTopLevelObject;

@end
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's called RestKit Relationships. Check out the wiki here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#relationships.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a nil key path:

```
RKEntityMapping *featureMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:...];
[featureMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"name"]];
featureMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"name" ];
```

Then, on your top level object mapping, define the relationship:

```
[topMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"features" toKeyPath:@"features" withMapping:featureMapping]];
```

In your feature (in the model), `myTopLevelObject` should be defined as a bi-directional relationship to the top level object.

Comment: I can't get this working. Is this line [featureMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"name"]]; 
The same as 
NSDictionary *featuresAttributeMappings = @{@"name":@"name"};
[featureMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: featuresAttributeMappings];

Comment: @MazenKasser, no, it isn't, the nil is required.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Yes sorry the nil is required here. But what I meant is that [featureMapping addPropertyMapping...] is the same as [featureMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:...]

Comment: @MazenKasser assuming you don't want a nil, yes

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Restkit 0.20+ then all you need to do is set the property that is representing the string array of your entity to Transformable.

For example, in this case your Feature entity has 3 properties:

```
someKey - String
otherKey - String
features - Transformable
```

Restkit will automatically map 'features' as a string array.

So once mapped, to access one of the strings in the features array would be as simple as:

`[Feature.features objectAtIndex:?]`

I just tried it and it works perfect.

Comment: this is a great solution. So you mean to create only one entity called Feature. What if I have the Features is an object with different key values. Create another entity for Features, but how that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can map an array of strings into a ManagedObject like that. However, since Feature only has one `name` property you could just store it as an array into your `MyTopLevelObject`. You can do that by adding a `features` property to `MyTopLevelObject` in your datamodel with the type `Transformable`. RestKit will automatically parse the features a NSArray with NSStrings. You can then get the features as following:

```
MyTopLevelObject *topLevelObject = ... // get the object from the persistent store
NSArray *features = (NSArray*)topLevelObject.features; // this will contain the features as NSString objects
```

Comment: wow you are a saver. Two days been wasted. I haven't heard before about Transformable. Thanks